# Mockito UnfinishedStubbingException in LamdaFunction

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

I am trying to mock

```java
this.restTemplate =
restTemplateBuilder
    .messageConverters(converter)
    .requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient))
    .build();
```

I am using following code

```java
doReturn(restTemplateBuilder).when(restTemplateBuilder).messageConverters(any(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class);
doReturn(restTemplateBuilder).when(restTemplateBuilder).requestFactory(lambdaCaptor.capture());
doReturn(restTemplate).when(restTemplateBuilder).build();
```

The `requestFactory` part is giving error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
```

Comment: I think you cannot use `captor` object -> `lambdaCaptor.capture()` inside a `Mockito.when()`

Comment: @Felipe how can I Mock it then?

Answer (score 1):

The error

> ERROR - org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: Unfinished stubbing detected here

happens because some of these cases:

1. missing thenReturn()
2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
3. you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed

I think that your example is close to the third item. You cannot use `captor` object -> `lambdaCaptor.capture()` inside a `Mockito.when()`.

Basically, you need to find a way to mock [HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html). There might be multiple ways to do it. I would start looking at how to mock the interface that it implements: [ClientHttpRequestFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestFactory.html). [Here on the official source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilderTests.java#L419-L433) there are some examples. This [answer also looks very close](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67475875/2096986) to what you need.